# Input doesn't change color according to the validation (rcc)

Tags: reactjs, validation, if-statement, state, arrow-functions

I want to validate the value that the user write in the input.
The browser works, creating a new room with the click of a `button` works, but the `input` doesn't change color according to the validation I set, why?

Inside `addRoomName` function I created `setState` for the value inside the room input

```
addRoomName=(e)=> {
this.setState({ room: e.target.value })
```

and **additionally** I created `setState` for the validation with the conditions

```
this.setState({ addRoomName: e.target.value });
if (e.target.value.length >= 6){
  this.setState({roomNameInputColor:'green'})
} else {
  this.setState({roomNameInputColor:'red'})
}
```

Is that may be the problem? because it seems that the react don't even recognize the validation but just the first setState (the one that bring the value that wrote in the room input)

So why the input doesn't change color?
I shared all the code
thanks!

App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import './App.css';
import Addroom from './components/Addroom.js'
import Room from './components/Room.js'

export default class App extends Component {
  state = {
    roomsList:[{room:'',color:''}],
  }

  create = (r, c) => {
    this.setState({ roomsList: [...this.state.roomsList, { room: r, color: c }] })
  } 

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>My Smart House</h1>
        {this.state.roomsList.map((element) => {
          return <Room r={element.room} c={element.color} />
        })}

        <Addroom add={this.create}/>
        
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Addroom.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

export default class Addroom extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      roomNameInputColor:'white',
    }
  }

  addRoomName = (e) => {
    this.setState({ room: e.target.value })
    this.setState({ addRoomName: e.target.value });

    if (e.target.value.length >= 6) {
      this.setState({ roomNameInputColor: 'green' })
    } else {
      this.setState({ roomNameInputColor: 'red' })
    }
  }

  addColor = (e) => {
    this.setState({ color: e.target.value })
  }

  createRoom = () => {
    this.props.add(this.state.room, this.state.color);
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <div>
        <input onChange={this.addRoomName} style={{ backgroundInputColor: this.state.roomNameInputColor }} placeholder='Name Your Room'/>
        <br/>
        <input onChange={this.addColor} placeholder='Whats The Room Color?'/>
        <br/>
        <button onClick={this.createRoom}>Create</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Room.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

export default class Room extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    
    this.state = {}
  }
    
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Room: {this.props.r} </h1>
        <h3>Color: {this.props.c} </h3>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you try storing `e.target.value` in a variable and use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks everyone, now it works, I did like you send guys to have effective code and also I changed this

```
 <input onChange={this.addRoomName} style={{backgroundInputColor:this.state.roomNameInputColor}} placeholder='Name Your Room'/><br/>
```

To this

```
 <input onChange={this.addRoomName} style={{backgroundColor:this.state.roomNameInputColor}} placeholder='Name Your Room'/><br/>
```

Because `backgroundColor` is a reserved word and while I tried to fix the problem I didn't saw that little important thing.. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In your `addRoomName` function, you are doing multiple setState in a row, where it's often a source of state confusions (that you are probably experiencing here).

Prefer to have a single call to the `setState()` method in your function like this:

```js
addRoomName = (e) => {
  const room = e.target.value;

  let roomNameInputColor = '';
  if (room.length >= 6) {
    roomNameInputColor = 'green';
  } else {
    roomNameInputColor = 'red';
  }

  this.setState({ room, addRoomName: room, roomNameInputColor });
}
```